# Automatic Cycling Carousel for several divs and different img

Tags: javascript, html, carousel

I am trying to write a function, that will automatically carousel cycle through img thumbs on my site with 12 different sets of images, which are just put together in one div. The javascript below works, but only as long, as I have the same amount of images in every div. I am also sure, that I took the long route of telling javascript, what to do in terms of variables so my question is, what should I change, so that I can have different amounts of img in my separate divs?

Thanks a lot for any tips!

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var u = document.getElementsByClassName("thumbs1");
  var v = document.getElementsByClassName("thumbs2");
  var w = document.getElementsByClassName("thumbs3");
  // and so on ...

  for (i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {
    u[i].style.display = "none"; 
    v[i].style.display = "none"; 
    w[i].style.display = "none";
    // ...
  }

  myIndex++;

  if (myIndex > w.length) {myIndex = 1}

  u[myIndex-1].style.display = "inline-block"; 
  v[myIndex-1].style.display = "inline-block";
  w[myIndex-1].style.display = "inline-block";
  // ...
 
  setTimeout(carousel, 1200); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```html
<div class="imageholder">
  <img class="thumbs1" src="image11.jpg">
  <img class="thumbs1" src="image12.jpg">
  <img class="thumbs1" src="image13.jpg">
  <img class="thumbs1" src="image14.jpg">
</div>

<div class="imageholder">
  <img class="thumbs2" src="image21.jpg">
  <img class="thumbs2" src="image22.jpg">
  <img class="thumbs2" src="image23.jpg">
</div>

<div class="imageholder">
  <img class="thumbs3" src="image31.jpg">
  <img class="thumbs3" src="image32.jpg">
  <img class="thumbs3" src="image33.jpg">
  <img class="thumbs3" src="image34.jpg">
  <img class="thumbs3" src="image35.jpg">
</div>

<!-- ... -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep counting the `myIndex` (so do not reset it) and use the [modulus `%` operator](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arithmetic.asp#Remainder) with the array length of each image set.

Further notes:

- The value of Timeout/Interval is in milliseconds. So 2000ms = 2s
- You do not need to get all elements' references again with each call to `carousel()`. Just do it once at the beginning.
- If something is not clear, please ask.

```js
var myIndex = 0;
var i;
var u = document.getElementsByClassName("thumbs1");
var v = document.getElementsByClassName("thumbs2");
var w = document.getElementsByClassName("thumbs3");

var allThumbs = [u, v, w];

var myInterval = setInterval(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds

function carousel() {
  myIndex++;

  for (i = 0; i < allThumbs.length; i++) {
    allThumbs[i][(myIndex - 1) % allThumbs[i].length].style.display = "none";
    allThumbs[i][myIndex % allThumbs[i].length].style.display = "inline-block";
  }
}
```

```css
.thumbs1:not(:first-child),
.thumbs2:not(:first-child),
.thumbs3:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageholder">
  <img class="thumbs1" src="image11.jpg" alt="1">
  <img class="thumbs1" src="image12.jpg" alt="2">
  <img class="thumbs1" src="image13.jpg" alt="3">
  <img class="thumbs1" src="image14.jpg" alt="4">
</div>

<div class="imageholder">
  <img class="thumbs2" src="image21.jpg" alt="1">
  <img class="thumbs2" src="image22.jpg" alt="2">
  <img class="thumbs2" src="image23.jpg" alt="3">
</div>

<div class="imageholder">
  <img class="thumbs3" src="image31.jpg" alt="1">
  <img class="thumbs3" src="image32.jpg" alt="2">
  <img class="thumbs3" src="image33.jpg" alt="3">
  <img class="thumbs3" src="image34.jpg" alt="4">
  <img class="thumbs3" src="image35.jpg" alt="5">
</div>
```

Comment: Hey MA-Maddin! Thank you very much. I understood and this works like a charm!